# If statements with multiple variables

Tags: c++, if-statement, comparison-operators

I'm trying to use `if` statement with multiple comparison operations but the `day` variable isn't working in my `if` statements.

Here's my code:

```
int day;
string rain;

cout << "What day of the week is it?" << endl;
cin >> day;

while (0 < day < 8)
{
    cout << "Is it raining? Please type 'yes' or 'no' " << endl;
    cin >> rain;

    if ((0 < day < 3) && (rain == "yes"))
    cout << "Read in bed" << endl;

    else if ((0 < day < 3) && (rain == "no"))
        cout << "Go out and play!" << endl;

    else if ((2 < day < 8) && (rain == "yes"))
        cout << "Take an umbrella!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No umberella needed" << endl;

    cout << "What day of the week is it?" << endl;
    cin >> day;
}

cout << "Invalid day sorry" << endl;
```

Getting `Read in bed` or `go out and play`, but never `Take an umbrella`.

My code also works if I put `day = 9`.

Comment: There are better coding practices than this.... try an infinite loop with `Invalid day sorry` as break statement. and the program can be structured safely to reach all endpoints

Comment: If an answer solves your problem then consider upvoting & marking it solved. Give the contributors some credit for the efforts :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need parentheses around the individual comparisons. `if(0 < day && day < 3 && rain == "yes")` and `if ((0 < day) && (day < 3) && (rain == "yes"))` mean the same thing. For experienced programmers, the second one is harder to read because you have to stop and figure out that the parentheses aren't actually doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with if statements and multiple variables, your `0 < day < 3` should actually read as `0 < day && day < 3`. BTW, you don't need to test it in every branch of the same if statement, it is unlikely to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot, still trying to understand the basics

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct your conditions involving `day` variable using logical AND (`&&`) operator.

For example, `0 < day < 8` means that you're testing `day` against two different values i.e. whether `day` is between this range. So, these two comparisons should be combined using logical operators and `&&` in your case. Therefore, it should be like this:

```
day > 0 && day < 8
```

Same goes for your other conditions where `day` is being compared.

---

For more details on logical operators, see reference:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

Answer (score 2):

Use `7 < day &&  day < 0`

Once you write `0 < day < 3` C++ evaluates one of it and then the comparison becomes **boolean < integer**

A better approach for your code I feel: I could reach all the endpoints

```
    while (true) {

        cout << "What day of the week is it?" << endl;
        cin >> day;

        if (7 < day &&  day < 0 ){
            cout << "Invalid day sorry" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Is it raining? Please type 'yes' or 'no' " << endl;
        cin >> rain;

        if (0 < day && day < 3) {
            if (rain == "yes") {
                cout << "Read in bed" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Go out and play!" << endl;
            }
        } else {
            if (rain == "yes")
                cout << "Take an umbrella!" << endl;
            else
                cout << "No umberella needed" << endl;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how C++ works:

```
0 < day < 3
```

You have to change it

```
day > 0 && day < 3
```